# R equivalent of Stata weights

Tags: r, stata, survey

In some of the demographic and health data, a  weight variable is assigned to the data-set (based on several parameters). Analyzing the data taking into account the weight variable is easy in Stata (and in SPSS). I could not find how this is done in R

What could be done in R for the following commands done in Stata? [Note that we just have weight variable and population correction factor, strata, and detail sampling are unknown]

`tab x y [iweight=weight]`

`mean x [iweight=weight]`

and so on

Comment: Why are you using `iweight` anyway? "iweights... have  no  formal  statistical  definition...  They are usually intended for use by programmers who want to produce a certain computation." (https://www.stata.com/manuals13/u11.pdf#u11.1.6weight). See also "Importance weights, unlike the other three types, do not have a specific formula and can only be used with certain commands; they are primarily useful to programmers..." https://www.reed.edu/psychology/stata/gs/tutorials/weights.html `iweight` acts different in different commands and isn't generally implemented in R AFAIK

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at with that comment is, it's hard to tell you how to do something in R unless that something is well defined. `iweight` doesn't have a statistical definition, so it may be hard to replicate, unless the "certain computation" they perform is documented really well. At least in the case of `mean`, that does not seem to be the case....  If you're wanting to actually do something statistical involving weighting, you may want to actually describe the calculation you want to perform, and someone might be able to tell you how to do that in R

Comment: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009/RJ-2009-018/RJ-2009-018.pdf  has comparisons of weighted survey data